# Accessing other class public variable in another class java

Tags: java, jframe, jlabel, netbeans-8

I'm creating an android app which connect to a server using socket connection. In server i have two classes(**server.java and MainFrame.java**) in same package.When the **connection** gets **accepted** then i **want to change** **variable value** which **belongs** to **other class**.I have **define** that variable **public** but still i can not achieve my goal.

So here i want to change a **JLable** value from **Server.class** when a connection is accepted.. but its not changing the value and remains with previous one.The label is on **JFrame**. I am using netbeans for writing the server code.

**Here is the first file:**

**Server.java**

```
package server;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Server extends Thread {
public static int SERVERPORT = 8002;
private boolean running = false;
public volatile boolean stop = false;
public Socket client = null;
ServerSocket sc = null;
final MainFrame framea = new MainFrame();//creating instance of second class

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    super.run();
    running = true;
    try {
        System.out.println("Server Has Started........ \nWaiting for client........");
        sc = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
        try {
            while (!stop && running) {
                client = sc.accept();
                System.out.println("Connection Accepted......");
                framea.labInfo.setText("Connected To Client");//HERE i want to change value
            }
            if (stop) {
                sc.close();
                client.close();
                System.out.println("Server Has Stopped");
                System.exit(0);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
 public void requestStop(){ 
   try{stop = true;
   sc.close();
   client.close();
   System.out.println("Server Has Stopped");
   }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Error"+e.getMessage());}
   }
}
```

**Second file:**

**MainFrame.java**

```
package server;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
private Server mServer;
public MainFrame() {
    super("MainFrame");
    //mServer = new Server();
    initComponents();
    setIcon();
    labInfo.setText("Not Connected");
    try{ ipAdd.setText(String.valueOf(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()));
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());}

}                     

private void connActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
            mServer = new Server();
            conn.setEnabled(false);
            labInfo.setText("Waiting for Connection.....");
            mServer.start();                
}                                    

private void disconnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    mServer.requestStop();
    labInfo.setText("Not Connected");
    conn.setEnabled(true);        
}                                       

public static void main(String args[]) {
          /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton conn;
private javax.swing.JButton disconn;
private javax.swing.JLabel ipAdd;
private javax.swing.JLabel ipAddLab;
public javax.swing.JLabel labInfo;
private javax.swing.JTextField port;
private javax.swing.JLabel portLab;
// End of variables declaration          
}
```

Comment: Get used to 
[Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html): Class names start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle i tried it with bt no luck :(

Comment: @NileshIndalkar I think in android you might havent got the libraries `swing` and `awt`

Comment: @user7185318 but android part hasnt come yet in the scene......means whenever i click on connect, in server its show command connection accepted but i want also change label

Comment: @NileshIndalkar : But why is it tagged as android then ?

Comment: @user7185318 my bad!! how to add libraries

Comment: @NileshIndalkar Probably you need something like `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI();` to update the screen ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138024/discussion-between-nilesh-indalkar-and-user7185318).

Comment: My suggestion is that you learn basic Java and OOP concepts. There are many tutorials around the net.

Comment: @m0skit0 i will but how can i get out of this issue?

Comment: By learning basic Java and OOP concepts. Otherwise you will just run in many other issues in the future. Better learn fishing than ask us for a fish. It is just my suggestion though :)

Comment: @m0skit0 if you know the solution then plz explain